# How Add new score to old score in update function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to add new score to old score in update function? I have been struggling to get my head round to adding my new score to the old score in update function with `Mathf.move` towards but not work!
Score increases to infinity.
I used `bool`, `while`, limited time nothing work.

I want to add remaining time left + current score.

```
void Start()
{
    LevelNumber = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;

    timertext.text = "00:" + secondLeft;
    nextTime = Time.time + delay + 2;

    VictoryPanel.SetActive(false);
    GameOverPanel.SetActive(false);

    cam = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<CameraManager>();
    //cam.Default();
    go = false;
    CountDownAnimimator.SetBool("countdown", true);
    currentScore = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("score");
    //PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();
}

void Update()
{
    scoretext.text = "Score: " + currentScore.ToString("0");
    if (timeleft <= 0)
    {
        timeleft = 0;
        cam.ChangeToEnd();
        //Time.TimeScale = 0;
        //timeisUp.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        //Restartbutton.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
    timertext.text = "" + Mathf.Round(timeleft);

    if (Time.time >= nextTime)
    {
        StartCoroutine(SetCollor());
        nextTime += interval;
    }
    if (timeleft > 0 && Time.time >= nextTime - 1)
    {
        if (Timer)
        {
            timeleft -= Time.deltaTime;
            go = true;
        }

        if (timeleft <= 10)
        {
            timertext.color = Red;
        }
        if (title1.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color == Green)
        {
            cam.ChangeToEnd();
            Timer = false;
            timertext.color = Green;
            VictoryPanel.SetActive(true);
            LevelComplete();
            StartCoroutine(UpdateScore());
        }
        else if (timeleft <= 0 && Titles[index].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color == Red)
        {
            cam.ChangeToEnd();
            timertext.color = Red;
            GameOverPanel.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    if (Time.timeSinceLevelLoad >= delay)
    {
        CountDownAnimimator.SetBool("countdown", false);
        cam.ChangeToPlay();
    }
}

public void RestartLevel()
{
    timeisUp.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    Restartbutton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    Time.timeScale = 1;
    timeleft = 40;
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
}

public void NextLevel()
{
    //timeisUp.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    //Restartbutton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    //Time.timeScale = 1;
    timeleft = 40;
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
}

public void BackToMenu()
{
    //timeisUp.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    //Restartbutton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    //Time.timeScale = 1;
    timeleft = 40;
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
}

IEnumerator SetCollor()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Titles.Length; i++)
    {
        while (used.Contains(index))
        {
            index = Random.Range(0, Titles.Length);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
    used.Add(index);
    Titles[index].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Red;

}

void Finish()
{
    //GameObject.Find("Player").SendMessage("Finish");
    timertext.color = Green;
}

void LevelComplete()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MaxLevel") == LevelNumber)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MaxLevel", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MaxLevel") + 1);
    }

}

IEnumerator UpdateScore()
{
    Count = Mathf.MoveTowards(Count, timeleft, Time.deltaTime * 3.0f);
    currentScore = currentScore + Count;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("score", currentScore);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

Comment: dont you just want to add remaining time left to score when level is complete?

Comment: yes but in update function not working

Comment: Define "doesn't work." What is it that you expect and what is it that happens instead?

Comment: I want to add the remainder of the timeleft to currentscore smoothly like lerp and save it and in new level add again not equal to timeleft everytime

Comment: why do you want to do it in update, not just when the level is complete

Comment: because i want when sprite change to green level victory panel show up, how can not put in update?

Comment: if (title1.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color == Green)
        {
            cam.ChangeToEnd();
            Timer = false;
            timertext.color = Green;
            VictoryPanel.SetActive(true);
            LevelComplete();
            StartCoroutine(UpdateScore());
        }

Comment: the only things that *have* to be in update are things you want to run every frame, everything else can be done, anywhere else, and on requirement

Comment: yes i know but i don't know how solve this without update, you can help me?